# Set DB Alias in docker container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to containerize a Web API project using [aspnet Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/). My web API needs to use a connection string with datasource = `<DB alias>`. I can use cliconfg.exe to set the DB alias on Windows. However I'm not able to set the DB alias in aspnet docker image as it does not have SQL client tools installed on it.

Is there a way I can install SQL client tools on my docker container and be able to deploy the Web API with connection string having DB alias?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with this, especially because I used linux. If you only wanted to use this alias inside mssql database you could add host alias to /etc/hosts by adding in docker command line 
**--add-host=myDbAlias:127.0.0.1**

On **Linux** your should just add to hosts mapping to your aliases, and that's all.

On **Windows**
Adding aliases should be placed in this branches of Windows Registry on Client side machine.

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo

Inside put Key as Your aliasNameServer and in data put "DBMSSOCN,YourRealServerName"  where YourRealServerName = your real server name

You could of course add your alias to hosts also, but if you have no privilege to access system files, you can use registry solution